# trying to click on an webElement which is only visable after clicking on another web elemnt in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

i have a page with number of clickable elements which is only visible when clicking on another elements (menus which open and enable another clickable elements)
i want to write a generic code which will enable me to handle a page which contain a lot of drop downs scenario like this.

the HTML look something like this (multiple a few more time)

`<div class="mini-menu" g-click="headerClicked(data.leftLink)>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="menuItemClick(item)">
   </li>
</div>`

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? also what is your question? Please provide more details, code, page before and after opening menus.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `FindBys` that aren't cached you should be able to do something like this since the `IWebElement` isn't found until you use it:

```
public SomePageObject ClickMenuItem(IWebElement menu, IWebElement item)
{
    //click the menu
    //wait for item to be visible
    //click the item
}
```

If you're not using `FindBys`, something like this since you'll have to find the element after it becomes visible:

```
public SomePageObject ClickMenuItem(IWebElement menu, By item)
{
    //click the menu
    //Wait for Element to be visible with the item By
    //click the item
}
```

There are a lot of answer out here on how to do the pseudo code part so I'll let you give that a shot. Let me know if you have trouble.